# Asp.NET Web Form - changing "<" and ">" characters to their entities

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am beginner to C# and Asp.NET and I've started with Asp controlls etc. Whenever I click button **btWyswietl** I want all characters ">" and "<" from text field **tbTekst** to be changed to their entities f.e.:

`I love < and >` to be changed to: `I love &lt; and &gt;`

I have a form like that:

```
<form id="formDruga" runat="server">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Podaj dowolny tekst:</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="tbTekst" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Button ID="btWyswietl" runat="server" Text="Wy&#347;wietl tekst" OnClick="btWyswietl_Click" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tekst po przetworzeniu:</tr>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lbTekstPo" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

and my **.aspx.cs** looks like this:

```
public partial class Druga : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbCzas.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }

    protected void btWyswietl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbTekstPo.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(tbTekst.Text);
    }
}
```

but it does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: `Server.HtmlEncode` instead of decode is what you mean right?

Comment: i changed to Server.HtmlEncode but nothing changes f.e. when i write 23 > 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of your tags do not have a matching begin/end tag i.e.

```
     <td>Tekst po przetworzeniu:</tr>
```

Other than that you need to enclose the html encoded text withing an html element such as a div. This can be done in you click method like this:

```
    protected void btWyswietl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var encoded = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(tbTekst.Text);

        using (System.IO.StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
            {
                writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div);
                writer.WriteEncodedText(encoded);
                writer.RenderEndTag();
            }

            lbTekstPo.Text = stringWriter.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Can you explain what are those clases responsible for? I mean StringWriter and HtmlTextWriter. Why do I need to do it in this way? When I encode text to HTML I get correct entities etc. but when I display that text in label I still get special character? Why does it happen?

Comment: StringWriter is like StringBuilder in that it is more efficient in that it does not create a new string object each time it appends. The HtmlTextWriter is specific to writing text for html elements. If you put a breakpoint at your orginial Server.HtmlEncode you would see that the text is encoded. Because you are assigning the text to an html control, the control will automatically decode the text.